# Assembling some code out-of-line with nasm macros

Tags: performance, assembly, optimization, x86, nasm

Consider a nasm macro that is used to inject some assembly whenever it is called, in this case to test whether the passed argument is equal to 42:

```
%macro special_handler_if_42 1
    cmp  42, %1
    jne  %%skip
    ; some additional assembly to handle the %1 == 42 case
    push %1
    push 42
    call some_func
%%skip:
%endmacro
```

In the case it *is* equal we perform some additional action, otherwise we just continue with the code following the macro. So far, so good.

Now I want to write the macro in a way that's functionally identical, except that the "equals 42" case, which happens to be very rare, is moved "out of line", so that the fall-through (no jump) case is the default one, something like (not shown in macro form now):

```
    cmp  42, rax
    je  equals_42
jump_back:
    ; the rest of the code that follows the macro
    ret

    ; somewhere outside the current function
equals_42:
    push rax
    push 42
    call some_func
    jmp jump_back
```

This will be more efficient at execution time and also potentially conserve i-cache space. I'm not sure how to write a macro with a non-local effect like that. Ideas welcome.

Comment: Linker sections?  That's going to mean 6-byte `jcc rel32` instead of 2-byte `jcc rel8` to the bottom of a short function, though, for the inline part.  The out-of-line part may have to be *very* rare for that to be better than the bottom of the function.  (Typically within the same page / TLB entry).  But maybe better packing of other functions that use it means more TLB and I-cache hits in the rest of your code.

Comment: Yeah I had considered say `.text.unlikely`. In my use case the unlikely case is "never" used more or less (it indicates a failed assert and terminates the program). So there is zero performance weight on that case (but the 2 extra bytes for `jcc` maybe hurts the normal case too).

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible for you (as assert case) to do `cmove eax,[42]` (maybe [ss:42] to have different fault code), and handle the failure in thrown exception? (I never coded an exception handler, but I guess there is a way to figure out which address failed, so you can catch "42" there, and `eax` is eax .. and probably you can catch the instruction code, should be enough to distinguish this in 90% of cases from real fails) ... oh, it's 8B long opcode... :-o

Comment: @Ped7g: `cmov` unconditionally loads a memory source operand.  You can't use it to get predicated *execution* of other uops; it's only a simple ALU uop that needs all 3 of its inputs ready before it can execute.  (FLAGS + 2 integers).  If you just wanted to fault, you'd use `org 0xdeadbeef` / `bad_condition:` once at the end of your file, and `jcc` to that in your macro.  (Or something that would make sure it's reachable with a rel32 in 64-bit code.)

Comment: @Ped7g - faulting is an interesting idea, but a bit extreme for what I'm looking for here, which is a (relatively) portable macro defined in an include file that you can just drop into an existing project and start using without writing a fault handler or anything. I also want to be able to communicate more than just two arguments to the handler (even though only two are shown above). Finally `cmove` is probably slower than `jcc` since (a) it doesn't fuse (b) executes on fewer ports on recent Intel and as multiple uops on older Intel (c) adds dependency chain.

Comment: NASM supports contexts and context labels. I have a prototype which uses a `assert_not_equal` macro to use at the test site and a `assertions_handler` to use after the function. Multiple `assert_xxx` macros are supported. However I'm still working on how to pass the `assert_xxx` macros arguments to the `assertions_handler`. As now, I hardcoded them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind splitting the macro into two macros, one performing the test and one handling the assertion, then you can use [NASM's context stack](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.7).

I imagined a system of macros of the form `assert_XXX` that are all pretty similar and perform specific tests.
A single `assertions_handler` past the end of the function will generate any handler needed.

Since this system uses the context stack, you should be able to use it multiple times for different functions.
Basically, each `assert_XXX` function will push a context on the stack and the `assertions_handler` will consume them all.

`assert_XXX` will also define context local macros `argX` to pass its argument to the handler, so there is no need to hardcode anything.

```
BITS 64

%macro assert_not_equal 2
    ;Create and push a new context (The name is optional but goodpractice)
    %push assert_equal_ctx

    %define %$arg1 %1
    %define %$arg2 %2

    cmp  %1, %2
    je  %$handler

%$jump_back:

%endmacro


%macro assert_greater 2
    %push assert_greater_ctx

    %define %$arg1 %1
    %define %$arg2 %2

    cmp  %1, %2
    jbe  %$handler

%$jump_back:

%endmacro

%macro assertions_handler 0

    %rep 1000

        %ifctx assert_equal_ctx

        %$handler:
            push %$arg1
            push %$arg2
            call somefunc
            jmp %$jump_back

            %pop assert_equal_ctx

        %elifctx assert_greater_ctx

        %$handler:
            push %$arg1
            push %$arg2
            call somefunc2

            %pop assert_greater_ctx

        %else

            %exitrep

        %endif
    %endrep
%endmacro


;
;TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST
; 


assert_not_equal rax, 5

nop
nop
nop

assert_greater rax, 8

nop
nop
nop

ret

assertions_handler

;
; Handler functions
;

somefunc:
    ret

somefunc2:
    ret
```

The maximum number of assertions per function is set to 1000, you can increment it up to 2<sup>62</sup>.

Comment: Thanks, this looks great! You guessed correctly that my use case is generic assert macros. Splitting each assert into two would not be OK, but having one `assertion_handler` per file is just fine (as I understand it, there is no restriction limiting it to 1-per function - you can choose when to put the `assertions_handler` and it will "flush" all the stacked up assertions, if I understand correctly?). I had looked at the context stack stuff, but didn't see the applicability - and couldn't find a way to "save stuff for later". I guess this does mostly preclude use in the case where the user ...

Comment: ... is already using the context stack for something else, unless those uses are "well nested" with respect to the assertion stuff (e.g., it would be fine if between some asserts the user pushed and then fully popped contexts - but it would not be OK if the user pushed a context and didn't pop it before `assertion_handler` since the assertion handler would fail to handle all accumulated assertions (in the `%else` case), right?

Comment: @BeeOnRope, Yes, that are basically the downsides of using the stack context. NASM allows for looking arbitrarily deep into the context stack by using more `$` in the `%$` operator (eg `%$$$$`) but I don't now if this can be done generically/programmatically

Comment: I'm sure I understand how the code could possibly look if splitting the macro is not OK.

Comment: Yeah what I meant is that  a split is "no good" if you have to do it 1:1 for each assert call (i.e., you write 10 asserts, you need 20 macro calls, potentially duplicating arguments), but having a split like your proposal where many assert calls can be handled by one `assertions_handler` is fine. One way a macro could work without a split at all would be, I think, to move the "assembly point" somewhere else temporarily in order to write the out-of-line code, like another section. I do that to write to `.rodata` in the middle of a macro assemblying code for example.

Comment: Can I use your approach in [nasm-utils](https://github.com/travisdowns/nasm-utils) (MIT-licensed), of course with attribution?

Comment: @BeeOnRope Of course, with or without attribution :)